# Probabilistic Hough lines returning only angled lines

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm attempting to parse floorplans to turn them into an array of line coordinates using HoughLinesP in opencv-python and the function is only returning lines that are angled and have no relation to the actual lines in my image.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

# Read image and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('C:/Data/images/floorplan/extremely basic.png', -1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get lines with probabilistic hough lines
found_lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(gray, 1, 3.14 / 160, 100,
                              minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=10)

# Loop through found lines and draw each line on original image
for line in found_lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# Show image, wait until keypress, close windows.
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is what's going to be returned with threshold 150 and 100 respectively:

[image]

[image]

[image: Original]

I've tried tinkering with all options and attempted non-probabilistic Hough lines to no avail.

Comment: whats your input image size? is it very small?

Comment: I have tried multiple images with multiple sizes and the same error occurs: randomly angled lines with no relation to the original image, but reacting to the threshold.

Comment: I guess maxLineGap=10 is the issue.   pixels between those lines is greater than 10 try 40 or 50

Comment: Can you share the source image so we can also try ? This kind of problems generally cos of the parameters you are assigning to that function

Comment: I've added the original image to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with image inversion and parameters. You have to do further adjustments as this does not give all lines.

The code is test on google colab. Remove `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` and replace `cv_imshow` with `cv2.imshow` for local usage.

#### Partial Image Ouput

[image]

#### Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Read image and convert to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 0)
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


s1, s2 = img.shape
new_img = np.zeros([s1,s2],dtype=np.uint8)
new_img.fill(255)


ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2_imshow(thresh1)


kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2_imshow(erosion)


# Get lines with probabilistic hough lines
found_lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(erosion, np.pi/180, np.pi/180, 10, minLineLength=4, maxLineGap=4)

# Loop through found lines and draw each line on original image
for line in found_lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(new_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    cv2_imshow(new_img)
    #cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# Show image, wait until keypress, close windows.
print("ORIGINAL IMAGE:")
cv2_imshow(img)
#cv2.imshow('image', img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```